# Is the swap partition encrypted?

Tags: partitioning, encryption, swap

Selecting the encryption option at install time to encrypt the home partition. Does this enable encryption of the swap partition or is the swap partition unencrypted. If the swap partition is unencrypted, how do I encrypt the swap and home partitions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default, selecting the “Encrypt my home directory” option at install time *will* encrypt your swap space¹ as well - at least in Ubuntu 10.04 and newer (I don't know when this was implemented, so it could well be earlier).

Technically, it uses the `ecryptfs-setup-swap` program to do the swap encryption.  You can use this tool if you want to encrypt your swap space post-install.

¹: This applies to both swap *partitions* and any swap *files* you may have set up.

Comment: how can i check via commandline if the swap-partition is encrypted?

Comment: Use the following command to check if the swap partition is encrypted: `sudo cryptsetup status cryptswap1`

Answer (score 2):

No, data written to the swap partition is done so in cleartext. If you're looking to encrypt your swap partition, then you may find [dm-crypt](http://www.saout.de/misc/dm-crypt/) useful. [This](https://www.antagonism.org/privacy/encrypted-swap-linux.shtml) article talks about applying dm-crypt to the swap area.

Comment: So encrypting home directory with ecryptfs during Ubuntu installation encrypt also swap partition or not?

Answer (score 1):

No, only the `/home` partition is encrypted. If you want more, you should use [LUKS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemsViaUbiquity). See also [Ubuntu help on encrypted fileystems](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystems).