# Verify if root is encrypted or just home -

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, encryption

Can I verify/check if a partition (root and home) is encrypted?

If it's not encrypted, can I encrypt after installing, or do I need to install again?

I want to have root and home partitions encrypted.

Details:

I have a new install of 13.10, along side windows 8 on a Dell XPS ([l521x](http://www.dell.com/uk/p/xps-15-l521x/pd))
Because I was installing alongside win 8, I chose the "something else" partitioning option, and can't remember the precise encryption settings I chose.

I think my home folder is encrypted, based on the fact that there are ".encryptfs" files in /home, but I gather this is folder only encryption.

I have three partitions dedicated to ubuntu, /, /home and /swap, ideally I'd like all three encrypted, but need my dual boot to still work with windows.

As it's a fresh install, it would be easier to re-install now than later when I've installed lots of bits and bobs.

*near duplicate questions*: this question "[how to I verify a partition in encrypted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144437/how-do-i-verify-a-partition-is-encrypted)" references an "article" (actually a question) which doesn't actually show you how to check if a partition is encrypted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check your partitions with the command `lsblk`.

If your root partition is encrypted, you should have output similar to the following

```
├─sdaX                              8:3    0    80G  0 part  
│ └─cryptvol (dm-0)               252:0    0    80G  0 crypt 
│   └─vgcrypt-lvcryptoroot (dm-1) 252:1    0    80G  0 lvm   /
```

The second line indicates a **dm-crypt** encrypted volume.

Comment: Thanks - am I right in thinking that if a partition isn't encrypted, I'm going to need to re-install?

Comment: Yes ([this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/96880/62612)). Also, since you mentioned dual-boot, you may need [these instructions](http://askubuntu.com/a/293029/62612) since at least in 13.04 the installers did not support setting up an encrypted dual boot.